# JavaScript clone a div but instead of cloning it once at a time, it multiplies

Tags: javascript, clonenode

I'm currently working on a quiz management system and creating the frontend for a create quiz page. Usually in question forms you can click on add new question/new answer and a new element showed up. But right now instead of creating one by one it start to multiply.

```
        <div class="createContainer">
            <form method="post" action="">
                <div id="createTable">
                    <div>
                        <label for="question">Question:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="question"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div id="createAnswer">
                        <label for="option">Option:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="option" />
                        <input type="radio" name="isCorrect">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-copy" onclick="duplicateAnswer()">New     Answer</button>
                </div>
                
                <button type="button" class="btn-copy" onclick="duplicateQuestion()">New     Question</button>
                <button type="submit">Create Quiz</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            function duplicateQuestion() {
                const node = document.getElementById("createTable");
                const clone = node.cloneNode(true);
                document.getElementById("createTable").appendChild(clone);
            }

            function duplicateAnswer() {
                const node = document.getElementById("createAnswer");
                const clone = node.cloneNode(true);
                document.getElementById("createAnswer").appendChild(clone);
            }
        </script>
```

I am new to JS so please enlighten me

Comment: because you are adding the rows inside of the table element so you keep cloning the original, plus the ones you added.

Answer (score 0):

You are cloning the complete `<div id="createAnswer">` and then appending the clone to that div. So the next time you'll clone it, it will contain the new element.

I suggest cloning the div, but append it after `<div id="createAnswer">`, not in it.

One way is to keep a reference to the `btn-copy`, and use `insertBefore` on the `parentElement` with the ref to the button to place it right before it.

Same goes for the questions, I've removed that to keep it simple for now.

```js
const insertBeforeElement = document.getElementById("btn-copy");

function duplicateAnswer() {
    const node = document.getElementById("createAnswer");
    const clone = node.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById("createAnswer").parentElement.insertBefore(clone, insertBeforeElement);
}
```

```html
<div class="createContainer">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div id="createTable">
            <div>
                <label for="question">Question:</label>
                <input type="text" name="question"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="createAnswer">
                <label for="option">Option:</label>
                <input type="text" name="option" />
                <input type="radio" name="isCorrect">
            </div>
            <button type="button" id='btn-copy' class="btn-copy" onclick="duplicateAnswer()">New     Answer</button>
        </div>

        
        <button type="submit">Create Quiz</button>
    </form>
</div>
```